# No me toma el script en ciertas dimensiones

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cordial saludo compañer@s, vengo realizando una pagina estilo demo, y le agregue la funcionalidad de dark y light, me funciona a la perfección en una resolución menor a 700px, pero al aumentarla esta no me coloca la clase .light en el body. les dejo  el .js

```
const btnSwitch = document.querySelector('#switch');

btnSwitch.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    document.body.classList.toggle('light');
    btnSwitch.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Comment: no tiene sentido que eso pase, con el codigo como esta deberia funcionar, quizas hay algo en el html o en los estilos como un `z-index` que hace que no sirva al aumentar el tamaño

Comment: vamos a revisar a ver si encuentro algo de lo que dices, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Buen día...

Estás seguro de que te funciona el toggle?, no veo en el código expresado que estés capturando el id del div o de cualquier elemento que quiere ejecutar solo veo el id del botón, pero no el que tenga contenida para agregar la clase... Esto --> `document.body.classList.toggle('light');` de por sí, eso, sin estar asociado a un id no funciona y debe ser el error que se te presenta.

Aquí el código de ejemplo:

HTML

```
 <button onclick="miFuncion()">Cambiar Clase</button>

<div id="miDIV">
  Aquí van los Elementos que se aplicará la clase
</div>
```

EL JavaScript

```
function miFuncion() {
  var element = document.getElementById("miDIV");
  element.classList.toggle("miEstilo");
}
```

El CSS sería:

```
.miEstilo{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```